# How to create a carousel with over-lapping view? [jsFiddle and ASCII art Included}

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/yxhzU/1042/

I'm trying to modify this example so that within the top carousel you are able to see 10% of the slides on either side.

Any help getting me pointed in the right direction would be great, thanks!

```
Viewable area would look something like this:
______    _________________________    _______
______|  |_________________________|  |_______
prev^            ^current^             ^next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yxhzU/1069/

I modified the plugin code you were using. I didn't test it fully, but this will give you a good idea of what you have to do.

I did the following modifications:

**Added 2 additional settings**

- itemwidth - This is a number from 1-100 which symbolizes the percentage of the carosel width that a single item takes up.
- startingoffset - Similarly it is the amount of starting space on the left is left open also percentage based (0-100)

Finally I modified all the calculations where the elements are wrapped and animated to use new "calculated" widths that include the above scaling.

The problem you were having is that many jquery plugins and the jquery UI stuff wrap your elements in additional "divs" and other DOM objects. So while you were using styles to change the width of your pages in the carosel, they were actually inside other things. I don't think you could make it work with only css anyway because the animation portions of the code were based off a width that was measured internally.

Edit:
Just FYI, I only viewed it in Chrome.

Comment: Wish I could give multiple up-votes and right answers. Thanks very much for all the work you put in to help explain this to me.

Comment: No problem, I like jquery and don't get to work with it much at work. This was interesting to tinker with.

Comment: One other thing I'd like to figure out is enabling some recalculations on window resize. Something like running the calculations again on `$(window).resize(function(){});` I'm happy to get in there, just thought I'd ask you for some advice on the best way to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: Should not be too hard. You will need to do a few things. 1. hook and event handler to the resize event on the window. 2. Make the handler reinitialize the sizes of all the containers in the carosel and finally 3. when resizing adust the current position to account for the change in size.  You'll need to be careful of the animation duration if you use that. I suspect you might get some wierd behavior. It's probably best sto skip animation on the resize event.